# indexOf IF statement looking for two values in one string using &&

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

I'm having problems using an `if` statement that uses the `indexOf` JS function to look for two different values in one string. If it does not find those two values then the if statement goes ahead and performs its function.

The aim of my `$.each` function is to track all external links that appear on my site and exclude all internal ones that feature the word 'sony' and '/pro' in it. The exception needs to be these two links (http://www.response.pro.sony.eu/ and http://www.assets.pro.sony.eu/ ).

So what I'm trying to do is avoid performing my function(assigning onClick="") if the `if` statements `indexOfs` find the two values I give it. This being '/pro' and 'sony'

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qj482/1/

I have provided a JSFiddle with my example code in it. I have a few links in there to test and make sure the process works but at the moment it is not.

In the Fiddle I need the following links to turn green(get tracked) and I'll list the ones that need to be avoided too.

```
http://www.pinewood.com/                - Tracked (green)
http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/hub/home      - Avodied (red)
http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/hub/tree      - Avodied (red)
http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/page/foo      - Avodied (red)
http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/page/bar      - Avodied (red)
http://www.response.pro.sony.eu/        - Tracked (green)
http://www.assets.pro.sony.eu/          - Tracked (green)
http://www.supermarsh.co.uk/pro-series  - Tracked (green)

http://www.sony.co.uk/                  - Avoided (red, has special .avoid class)
http://www.specialsite.com/             - Avoided (red, has special .avoid class)
```

Please note that the special '.avoid' class is only there as the client wants the ability to avoid any link if they want to override the detection.

How can I make this work? Here's my markup and JS

HTML/Markup

```
<p>Adipiscing elit. Ut diam eget lectus sit amet elementum orci tincidunt. Aenean nibh mi, rhoncus eget placerat sit amet, iaculis sed sapien. Aenean porta felis vel nibh pretium ac pretium tortor auctor. Nam et ipsum est. Vestibulum tristique vulputate condimentum. Pellentesque vel justo tellus. Phasellus velit sapien, <a href="http://www.pinewood.com">http://www.pinewood.com</a> Integer eros enim, vulputate vitae dignissim eget, <a href="http://www.sony.co.uk/" class="avoid">www.sony.co.uk/</a> quis augue. Curabitur <a href="http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/hub/home">www.sony.co.uk/pro/hub/home</a> lorem <a href="http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/hub/tree">www.sony.co.uk/pro/hub/tree</a> orem <a href="http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/page/foo">www.sony.co.uk/pro/page/foo</a> lorem <a href="http://www.sony.co.uk/pro/page/bar">www.sony.co.uk/pro/page/bar</a> molestie, <a href="http://www.response.pro.sony.eu">www.response.pro.sony.eu</a> sem <a href="http://www.assets.pro.sony.eu">www.assets.pro.sony.eu</a> vitae <a class="avoid" href="http://www.specialsite.com">www.specialsite.com.</a> lobortis, sapien nisl euismod purus, non commodo lacus est vel turpis. Cras <a href="http://www.supermarsh.co.uk/pro-series">www.supermarsh.co.uk/pro-series</a> iaculis sagittis nisl, sed ultricies erat condimentum quis.</p>
```

JavaScript/Jquery

```
//:not("avoid") skips any <a> tags with the class '.avoid'
$('a[href*="http://"]:not(".avoid")').each(function(index, element) {
var hrefContent = $(this).attr('href');
domainName = hrefContent.replace('http://','');

console.log(domainName);

//Skip adding GA tracking if href contains the word sony 
if(domainName.indexOf("/pro") == -1 && domainName.indexOf("sony") ==  -1)
    {
        $(this).attr('onclick','_gaq.push(["_trackEvent","Press Centre","email","'+domainName+'"]) ;_gaq.push(["b._trackEvent","Press Centre","email","'+domainName+'"]);').addClass('tracked');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('avoided')
    }

});
```

### Update

Thanks for all replies, but using the || operator seems to only partly work as when I add a simple link that is internal (www.sony.co.uk) and should be avoided and turned red as it contains the word 'sony'. Instead it is turned green and tracked. Can anyone rectify this problem?

Please see this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qj482/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, it is not exactly very pretty but gets the job done.

```
   //:not("avoid") skips any <a> tags with the class '.avoid'
   $('a[href*="http://"]:not(".avoid")').each(function (index, element) {
       var hrefContent = $(this).attr('href');
       domainName = hrefContent.replace('http://', '');

       console.log(domainName);

       //Skip adding GA tracking if href contains the word sony 
       if ((domainName.indexOf("\/pro\/") == -1 && domainName.indexOf("sony") == -1) || ((domainName.indexOf("sony") == -1 && domainName.indexOf("\/pro") > -1) || domainName.indexOf("www.response.pro.sony.eu") > -1 || domainName.indexOf("www.assets.pro.sony.eu") > -1)) {
           $(this).attr('onclick', '_gaq.push(["_trackEvent","Press Centre","email","' + domainName + '"]) ;_gaq.push(["b._trackEvent","Press Centre","email","' + domainName + '"]);').addClass('tracked');
       } else {
           $(this).addClass('avoided')
       }

   });
```

Comment: Ahh now that returns the result I want thank you. Yeah its not wildy pretty but as you say it works. Could I just ask how I might amend the suggestion you just made to incorporate jQueries inArray() function as I have just found out that indexOf is not supported very well in IE. If you could please just give me an example of how I'd update/change one of the indexOfs to inArray and I'll do the rest?

Comment: The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf() method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0. So in your code, the usage would be something like $.inArray("sony", domainName)

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example you may write

```
if(domainName.indexOf("sony.co.uk/pro") == -1)
    {
```

But actually you just need to replace && operator with || and everything works as you wanted.

```
if(domainName.indexOf("/pro") == -1 || domainName.indexOf("sony") ==  -1)
    {
```

That is because you wish to skip addresses which contain both `sony` and `/pro` which means that you  to track addresses with do not contain either `sony` or `/pro`.

Comment: OK so || means "or", and it does seem to work, but I didn't use the || operators because I thought I needed to make sure the URL had both "sony" and "/pro". Won't this method(using ||) mean I get unexpected results. Like URL that only have "/pro" in it? Although I can see that in the Fiddle using || has picked up my "/pro" example and turned that green. Not sure how that works, can you explain please?

Comment: No, the link will be tracked if it does not contain `sony` OR `/pro`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj482/7/).

I changed your javascript code so that avoided lnks turn red instantly.
The not avoided links will get a `.click()` event handler so that when you click the link, the _gaq code is fired and the link receives the extra class `.tracked`.

Also changed the operator to ||.

PS: commented out the [_gaq lines](http://jsfiddle.net/qj482/5/), because else the click handler will output an error.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your operator is wrong, you need to use || (or)

if(domainName.indexOf("/pro") == -1 || domainName.indexOf("sony") ==  -1)

Also, there are compatability problems with using indexOf(), the IE range don't support it in many of their older browsers.

As you're using jQuery, try using $.inArray() - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, does IE support inArray then?

Comment: $.inArray is actually a jQuery method, which is made compatible in all browsers (as far as I'm aware?)